# ASP.NET Core return file and redirect from same action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to make this flow: user posting some data to action then receives text file and redirects to another action.

So i need to return two "results" `File` and `RedirectToAction` in same response. Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: you can return a js code that would download the text and redirect

Answer (score 5):

First set up a model like this:

```
public class FileAndRedirect {

    public string FileContentAsBase64 { get; set; } 
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string RedirectURL { get; set; }

}
```

Then have a view:

```
@model FileAndRedirect

<a style="display:none" id="linker" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,@Model.FileContentAsBase64" download="@Model.FileName"></a>


<script>

    document.getElementById("linker").click();

    window.location = "@Model.RedirectURL";

</script>
```

Now you can return view:

```
return View(new FileAndRedirect{ ... })
```

Comment: This is great other than you have your javascript inside of style tags? I changed style to script tags, and i also added a dom ready event before executing the js. But other than that it was perfect. I just created a view in the shared location and now i can re-use everywhere. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by returning html content with download and redirect code based on Neville Nazerane's answer:

```
return Content("<!DOCTYPE html>" +
    "<html><head></head><body>" +                          
    $"<a style=\"display:none\" id=\"linker\" href=\"data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileData))}\" download=\"filename.txt\"></a>" +
    "</body>" +
    "<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){document.getElementById('linker').click(); window.location='/'}, false);</script>" +
    "</html>", "text/html");
```

Comment: you can use the latest c#'s `$` code on the whole thing keep it cleaner. you can add `@` too if you want your string in multi-lines. that way you can avoid the `" + "` everywhere